# Programmatically set the 'readonly' attribute of the editoptions options in jqGrid column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid's form editing feature.

Can I programmatically set the `readonly` attribute of the `editoptions` options in the `jqgrid`?

I need to determine if as specific field would be `readonly` or not, depends on one of the current row cell value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `readonly` attribute inside of `beforeShowForm` on the field (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3952654/315935)) or alternatively you can set/remove `readonly: 'readonly'` property (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7058114/315935)) of the `editoptions` for the column inside of `beforeInitData` which will be called *before* the edit form will be created. You can use `setColProp` for example to change `editoptions` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9019406/315935) an example).

To implement the changes depends on the cell value from some column you need just get the id of selected row with respect of `getGridParam` and then get the cell value using `getCell` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3021186/315935)).

In any cases I recommend you to use `recreateForm: true` option of form editing. It should be default options in my opinion.