# How to reset the dropdown value to the old value in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have  a simple dropdown with two values.Lets say Staus:active and inactive.
During the onchange event, I want to perfrom some validation and revert back if the validation fails. Thai is if I change from active-inactive and my validation fails, I should change the dropdown back to active. 
So far I am able to catch the on change event through the dataevents options of editOptions.
Below is my code, Thanks for the assist.

```
editoptions:{value:{Y:'Active',N:'Inactive'}, dataEvents:[
                             {
                                 type: 'change',
                                 fn: function(e) {
                                 alert("inside change trigger");
                                 $grid.setColProp('Status', { editoptions:{value:{Y:'Active',N:'Inactive'}}});
                                 }
                              }
                         ]}
```

I also read I have to set recreate form :true. I tried that also.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to consider to make the column non-editable or to readonly/disabled if the validation condition could be checked before editing will be started. It shows the user more clear that the field mayn't be changed.

Alternatively you can get `savedRow` parameter of jqGrid if you use inline editing mode or cell editing mode (with `var savedRows = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow")`). To get the "old" data in case of form editing you can just get the data of selected row by using `getGridParam` with `selrow` (or alternatively from the hidden field of the form which have `id="id_g"`. Something like `var serRowId =  $("#id_g").val();`) and by using `getRowData`/`getCell`.

Comment: Thanks oleg, Is it possible that I can disable the dropdown options in that case except the first one. How will I make that column readonly in the initial stage.

Comment: @user2375298: You are welcome! See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20498576/315935) for example for the corresponding demo. One can test `Status` of selected row inside of `beforeShowForm` and set `disabled` and `readonly` property (or `readonly="readonly"` and `disabled="disabled"` attributes) and add class `"ui-state-disabled"` to the row of editing form.